# Computing the error rate of rejecting the null hypothesis (from the decision theoretic perspective)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, decision-theory

Consider the following passage from the bottom of pg. 23 of *Statistical Decision Theory and Bayesian Analysis*:

> [image]

**Problem.** I'm having trouble understanding the red highlighted; it seems that the textbook has computed the error *not* of rejecting but of *either falsely rejecting or incorrectly accepting* the null hypothesis.

**Why I think this is so.** First, the "0-1" loss can be displayed on the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{$H_0: θ = θ_0$ } & \text{$H_1: θ = θ_1$ } \\ \hline
\text{$θ = θ_0$} & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{$θ = θ_1$ } & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

From this table it is clear that

$$
R(θ_0, δ) = (P_{θ_0}(\text{Keep $H_0$}) ⋅ 0) + (P_{θ_0}(\text{Type I error}) ⋅ 1) = α_0 = P_{θ_0}(\text{Type I error})
$$

and

$$
R(θ_1, δ) = (P_{θ_1}(\text{Type II error}) ⋅ 1) + (P_{θ_1}(\text{Reject $H_0$}) ⋅ 0) = α_1 = P_{θ_1}(\text{Type II error})
$$

Now suppose, as in the passage, that $α_0 = 0.01$ and $α_1 = 0.99$. Then

$$
\frac{α_0 + α_1}{2} = \frac{0.01 + 0.99}{2} = 0.5
$$

But this doesn't seem to show that "half of all rejections of the null will actually be in error"; instead, it shows that half of all tests (which result in either a rejection or an acceptance of $H_0$) will lead to error.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT.** I think I understand the solution. Basically, in order to compute the error rate when rejecting, one must calculate:

$$
\frac{P_{\theta_0}(H_1)}{P_{\theta_0}(H_1) + P_{\theta_1}(H_1)} = 
\frac{\alpha_0}{P_{\theta_0}(H_1) + P_{\theta_1}(H_1)} = {0.01 \over 0.01 + 0.01} = 0.5
$$

Is this the correct?

Comment: What I think you are missing is the fact that you can't know the percentage error of rejections unless you apply the type II error rate which reduces the total number of rejections.

Comment: @PhilH: Your comment led me to adjust my attempted solution to what I think is the correct answer. Does it look correct to you?

Comment: Your numbers are correct but I'm not sure your terms are. With a .01 probability of a type I error, 1 in 100 true nulls get incorrectly rejected. With a .99 probability of a type II error, only 1 out of 100 that should be rejected is correctly rejected.  This gives us 2 rejections one is correct the other isn't so the error rate is 50%.  I think your $P_{\theta_1}(H_1)$ should be $1 - P_{\theta_1}(H_1)$ to reflect the second 0.01 number in the denominator.